# CSS box shadow animation on table cell with background color

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to animate a table's row with box shadow. The first column is fixed and has background-color property. It looks those two thing messes up the animation. See below the snippet and the JsBin. Stackoverflow is complaining that my post is mostly code, but I think the gif is self explining.

[image]

```css
tr.pulse-row {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px
}

td.is-fixed-left {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;  
  z-index: 3;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pulse-row">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/xezedepima/7/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:0` to all rows except for the `.pulse-row`.

```css
tr {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

tr.pulse-row {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
  z-index:1;
}



@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}

body {
  padding: 20px
}

td.is-fixed-left {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;  
  z-index: 3;
  position: sticky;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pulse-row">
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td class="is-fixed-left">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Integration for the request in the comment.**

I think it is not possible to solve the problem, because one level is above and one below, and the background will always cover the shadow of the element below. But you can work around the problem (if the page background is a solid color and in this case considering white color).

Use an alpha `background-color` for the fixed `td`.

From this: `background-color: #f9f9f9;`

To this: `background-color: #5c5c5c0f;`

[Here the JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/6h0qLvxu/1/)

Comment: thanks for the solution. A follow up question: If I have more than one row with `pulse-row` class, a portion of the effect is missing. Here is a JsBin to explain: https://jsbin.com/xezedepima/9/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

When you use css animation, it will create an other context for stacking with `z-index`.

So you have to add `position:relative` in your class with animation to use `z-index` correctly.

```
tr.pulse-row {
      animation: pulse 1s infinite;
      position:relative;
      z-index:99;
    }
    
    @keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
      }
      70% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
      }
    }
    
    body {
      padding: 20px
    }
    
    td.is-fixed-left {
      background-color: #f9f9f9;  
      z-index: 3;
      position: sticky;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. A follow up question: If I have more than one row with `pulse-row` class, a portion of the effect is missing. Here is a JsBin to explain: https://jsbin.com/xezedepima/9/edit?html,css,output